Trouble matching the theoretical results with the LTspice simulation of a boost converter
I want to boost from 12 V to 13 V, this got me the duty cycle D = 0.076.
This is my boost circuit:

And this is my result in steady state:

The green line is the load voltage. Why doesn't it even touch 13 V? The duty cycle in the simulation is 5%.
The blue line is the inductor current, it's just to show if at least the current is correct, because in some other simulations it isn't even linear.
I tried changing the values of the resistor, capacitance, inductor, and the graph behavior varied considerably, but I don't know why.
In my real world problem I just have a vague idea of the load resistor being 2 Ω, so I don't want to change this value in the simulation.
I want to boost 12 V to 13 V to power a motor inside a miniboat. The DC-DC boost converter described in Hart's book was the first thing I thought of. I wanted to do a reliable simulation first.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The average current through D1 is expected to be over 6A, peak current will be maybe 50% higher, so a 1A diode won't cut it.
10μF is a bit low to smooth a 6A current
You will need to adjust D to account for the diode drop. Here's a simulation with a bigger diode (which is still dissipating more than 4W according to the simulation):

The default DC resistance of the inductor in LTspice is 0.001Ω. That's probably optimistic unless you buy an overrated inductor.
The output voltage will change with the loading because of non-ideal behavior in the components. If you want to have a more stable voltage you'll have to add feedback and a controller to adjust the duty cycle.

Hello Mr. Pefhany, thanks for your response, I can understand more now. What's this feedback to adjust the duty cycle? Is it a tool to control the duty cycle during the operation of the circuit? Where can I read more about this? Thanks.

It's switching power supply theory and there is a LOT of information out there. For a one-off if you want to build it yourself you might look at boost converter controller ICs which use an external MOSFET. LT (now owned by Analog Devices) have some nice ones, and good application notes, however they are rather proud of them.
